# How to set office hours only in Bootstrap 3 Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker for date and time selection.

I set all previous days disable but I am confusing in to set office hours only in hours selection. Here I attached one image.And my jQuery code is:

```
$('#appointment_end_datetime').datetimepicker({
   useCurrent: false,
   format: "Y-m-d h:i:s",
   minDate: d,
   defaultDate: d });
```

Please check [image: sanpshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead to use minDate and defaultDate you can use: [enabledhours](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enabledhours) and the event [dpchange](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange):

```js
$('#appointment_end_datetime').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: "Y-M-d H:ss",
  sideBySide: true,
  enabledHours: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
  var beginningTime = moment({h: +e.date.format('H'), s: +e.date.format('ss')});
  var endTime = moment({h: 18, s: 0});
  if (endTime.isBefore(beginningTime)) {
    $('#appointment_end_datetime').data('DateTimePicker').date(e.date.format("Y-M-d H:00"));
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='appointment_end_datetime'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! a lot buddy